# Accessing WebService Exception (SOAP-Fault) in Struts2 application

Tags: web-services, jsp, struts2

I'm developing a WebService with JAX-WS. In this WebService, I have a "DatabaseQueryFault" as SOAP-Fault:

```
    <wsdl:operation name="executeCustomQuery">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:executeCustomQueryRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:executeCustomQueryResponse"></wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="DatabaseQueryFault" message="tns:DatabaseQueryFault"></wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>

        <xsd:element name="databaseQueryFault" type="tns:databaseQueryFault" />
        <xsd:complexType name="databaseQueryFault">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="reason" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

The implementing Java-method has this header

```
public QueryResponseResultset executeCustomQuery(ExecuteCustomQuery parameters)
     throws RemoteException, DatabaseQueryFault {
```

Every time an exception is thrown, for example a SQLException, I "transform" it into an DatabaseQueryFault:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DatabaseQueryFault(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This works very fine until here: if I send an incorrect query, I get a soap response containing the DatabaseQueryFault including all the data

```
<soapenv>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
      <faultstring></faultstring>
      <detail>
         <ns1:databaseQueryFault xmlns:ns1="http://daga/knowledgebase/webservice">          
         <reason>Unknown column 'test14' in 'field list'</reason>  
         </ns1:databaseQueryFault>
         <ns2:exceptionName xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
             daga.knowledgebase.webservice.DatabaseQueryFault
         </ns2:exceptionName>
         <ns3:stackTrace xmlns:ns3="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
```

But now there comes the problem :-) My WebService Client is a Struts2 web app. There I use the native exception handling of struts2 (struts.xml):

```
<global-exception-mappings>
  <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

Now I want to access the details of my soap error within my jsp error page, but the fields are empty:

```
<p>
   <s:property value="exception" /><br />
   <s:property value="exception.message" /><br />
   <s:property value="exception.reason" />
</p>
```

How can I access the data of my WebService exception in my jsp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't have direct access to a *real* exception, unless you create and throw one.

Whether you handle this case with S2 exception handling (I'm kind of "meh" on that in this case) or not, you'll need to turn the return message into something of value to the user. You could transform the XML into something human-readable, or create an exception capturing the relevant information that's specific to your app.

Comment: I see... you mean that I should catch the WebService (JAX-WS) in my Java code, throw there a new "normal" exception and handle this one in my S2 files?

Comment: Sorry; missed the followup. More or less, yes--because the exception is encapsulated in the SOAP message, there's no actual application exception, unless you create one. Whether or not it should be an app exception, or just reported as a normal app error condition, is often a matter of preference.